# query for roww returning the first element of a group in db2

Tags: sql, db2

Suppose I have a table filled with the data below, what SQL function or query I should use in db2 to retrieve all rows having the FIRST field FLD_A with value A, the FIRST field FLD_A with  value B..and so on?

```
  ID   FLD_A    FLD_B
  1    A        10
  2    A        20
  3    A        30
  4    B        10
  5    A        20
  6    C        30
```

I am expecting a table like below; I am aware of grouping done by function `GROUP BY but how can I limit the query to return the very first of each group?`

Essentially I would like to have the information about the very first row where a new value for FLD_A is appearing for the first time?

```
  ID   FLD_A    FLD_B
  1    A        10
  4    B        10
  6    C        30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it works in sql

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM Table1 GROUP BY FLD_A)
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way to approach this problem is with window functions and `row_number()` in particular:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by fld_a order by id) as seqnum
      from table1
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

(This is assuming that "first" means "minimum id".)

If you use `t.*`, this will add one extra column to the output.  You can just list the columns you want to avoid this.